# Sitefinity DesignerView add choices to custom FormControlsToolboxName

Tags: sitefinity

I am building this FormControls widget and have added some controls like `sf-html-field` and `sf-image-field`. I am at the point where I want to add the Choices and not sure how best to do that. I want to it work the same way the built-in MultipleChoiceField control work.

DesignerView.Simple

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="heading-text">Label (Question)</label>


        <sf-html-field class="kendo-content-block"
                       sf-model="properties.Question.PropertyValue">
        </sf-html-field>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image-field" class="m-top-sm">@Html.Resource("Image")</label>
        <sf-image-field class="sf-Media--info modal-settings modal-settings-space"
                        sf-model="properties.ImageId.PropertyValue"
                        sf-image="selectedImage"
                        sf-provider="properties.ImageProviderName.PropertyValue"
                        sf-media-settings="@SettingsHelpers.GetMediaSettings("Image")"
                        id="image-field">
        </sf-image-field>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="heading-text">Choices</label>

    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Add]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the implementation of the default designer view here:

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Forms/Mvc/Views/MultipleChoiceField/DesignerView.Simple.cshtml#L20-L64

Comment: Can I see the model?

Comment: Also is there a js file I see something like this ng-click="addItem()" and it looks to be calling a js function ?

Comment: The js files are here: https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/tree/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Forms/Mvc/Scripts/MultipleChoiceField and the models are here: https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/tree/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Forms/Mvc/Models/Fields/MultipleChoiceField

Comment: Do I need all the of the js files? or just one of them?

Comment: try with only the one you need and see if the other will be taken from the default location

Comment: in that DesignerView.Simple.cshtml I dont see how it know what js file to use do I need to add any includes?

Comment: I added a image of what it is looking like with that view